# java howto test if a double has a ending zero like 9.0, and if so remove the zero

Tags: java, string, double

I have different file sizes and need to create a user friendly output.

The size is a double like 0.5MB, 2.1MB.
Sometimes I get 2.0MB because I use the:

```
Double line = (double) size/(double)(1024*1024);
DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("0.0");
String result = dec.format(line);
```

I want to remove the zero from the the above if `result==2.0`
Think I need to create a new `Double` or maybe do string arrhythmic
Any suggestions?

Comment: Check out regular expressions.

Comment: Why do you first convert it to a string using that 0, and then want to remove it? Maybe you should choose a different decimal format.

Comment: Do you want it to display 2MB if and only if it's *exactly* 2MB? Or do you want it to display "2MB" if it's 2.018MB?

Comment: yes i want to dislay 2MB if and only if it's exactly 2MB? and 2.12MB if it is 2.12

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `new DecimalFormat("0.#")`.